# HTML5 Sortable on both children as well as parent element make Parent to get sorted when sorting children inside it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

i have a list of todo item categories and each category will contain a list of todos. 
I have used "Sortables" on the todos inside categories so that one an sort the order of todos inside a category.

Now i wish to add sortables to Categories also, so that the user can sort the whole category. 
I have the DOM like this

```
    <ul id="ToDos">
      <li id="Cat-1"> 
          <ul class='collecton'> 
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Cat-2"> 
          <ul class='collecton'> 
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Cat-3"> 
          <ul class='collecton'> 
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="Cat-4"> 
          <ul class='collecton'> 
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
            <li class='todoItem'></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I gave sortable on these using this

```
    $('.collection').sortable();
    $('#ToDos').sortable({grid: [100, 50]});
```

Now the problem is that when i dont have sortable in "#ToDos", the sorting of "#collection"(i.e., the sorting of todoItems inside each category) works very well. When I give sortable on "#ToDos", sorting of each Category works, but the sorting of Category also happens when im sorting the todoItem inside the category i.e., the Category is also changing its order when the todoItem in the category is being sorted.

Please help me solve this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: try defining what element type/selector is to be sorted in the options in `$('#collection').sortable({options})`

Comment: Can yu be more specific, i dont get what yu are saying, Im actually a new bee for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use item option of jquery sortable to specify which elements you want to be sortable

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

In your case,

```
$('#collection').sortable(
    items: "> li"
);
```

Hope this helps

Take a look at this.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

When you start the dragging of the todoItem, the event bubbles up to your parents and since your category is also sortable, it starts dragging as well.

Try something like this,

```
$('.collection li').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry.. that didn't work..! moving the todo item in collection moves the category also

Comment: Is it a typo that u have multiple Id's with the name 'collection'. If not, can you switch them to class and see if you are getting what you want ?

Comment: yeah.. its a mistake i done here.. it is class only. It isn't working  still.

Comment: i did look at the edit.. I wasnt able to trigger the start event at all.. I added that function and used a console.log inside it. but nothing is being displayed in the console, i.e., the event is not being triggered..

Comment: moreover, i have another simple html page with similar structure. in that it works even without using stop propagation. So i went to inspect those elements html and found that in the html which this working, the class of the parent div for which sortables is added is chnaged like this 
<div class="colection ui-sortable">
 <li></li>
</div>
but here in which it is not working, the a "draggable = true" is added to the children and no change in class name of parent is made. Like this
<div class="collection">
 <li draggable=true> <li>
</div>

these differences mean something?

Comment: Sorry I put up the wrong markup by mistake. Edited the markup

Comment: that was not a issue.. i noticed it and used with correction itself when i tried. that start event callback is not triggered at all.

Comment: did u changed this ? $('.collection')  to  $('.collection li')